# Kubernetes, ALB : ALB not getting created for via ingress-service

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I am working on creating an ALB for 2 services together, with the annotation : merged. It's not working out. I can't see much action in logs as well. What am I doing wrong? Worker nodes have the ALB ingress policy as mentioned in AWS docs(adding the policy below as well). Kubernetes is not complaining, but ingress-service is not getting an Address, and no ALB or target group is getting created.

ALB-controller :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: alb-ingress-controller
  name: alb-ingress-controller
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: alb-ingress-controller
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 1
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: alb-ingress-controller
    spec:
      containers:
        - args:

            - --ingress-class=alb
            - --cluster-name=CLUSTER_NAME
            - --aws-vpc-id=vpc-XXXXXXX
            - --aws-region=REGION
          env:
            - name: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
              VALUE: XXXXXX
            - name: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
              value: XXXXX
              image: 894847497797.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/aws-alb-ingress-controller:v1.0.0
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          name: server
          resources: {}
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      serviceAccountName: alb-ingress
      serviceAccount: alb-ingress
```

ALB-ingress-service :

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: auth-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: merge
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: instance
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: ARN
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP":80,"HTTPS": 443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.ssl-redirect: '{"Type": "redirect", "RedirectConfig": { "Protocol": "HTTPS", "Port": "443", "StatusCode": "HTTP_301"}}'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/subnets: SUBNET-1,SUBNET-2
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/security-groups: SG-1,SG-2
    # allow 404s on the health check
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-path: "/"
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/success-codes: "200,404,302"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: host.domain.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /*
            backend:
              serviceName: magento-develop
              servicePort: 80
    - host: sub-domain.host.domain.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /*
            backend:
              serviceName: supplier-service
              servicePort: 80
```

IAM policy :

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "acm:DescribeCertificate",
                "acm:ListCertificates",
                "acm:GetCertificate"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress",
                "ec2:CreateSecurityGroup",
                "ec2:CreateTags",
                "ec2:DeleteTags",
                "ec2:DeleteSecurityGroup",
                "ec2:DescribeAccountAttributes",
                "ec2:DescribeAddresses",
                "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                "ec2:DescribeInstanceStatus",
                "ec2:DescribeInternetGateways",
                "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
                "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
                "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
                "ec2:DescribeTags",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
                "ec2:ModifyInstanceAttribute",
                "ec2:ModifyNetworkInterfaceAttribute",
                "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupIngress"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "elasticloadbalancing:AddListenerCertificates",
                "elasticloadbalancing:AddTags",
                "elasticloadbalancing:CreateListener",
                "elasticloadbalancing:CreateLoadBalancer",
                "elasticloadbalancing:CreateRule",
                "elasticloadbalancing:CreateTargetGroup",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DeleteListener",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DeleteLoadBalancer",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DeleteRule",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DeleteTargetGroup",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DeregisterTargets",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeListenerCertificates",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeListeners",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeLoadBalancers",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeLoadBalancerAttributes",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeRules",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeSSLPolicies",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeTags",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeTargetGroups",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeTargetGroupAttributes",
                "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeTargetHealth",
                "elasticloadbalancing:ModifyListener",
                "elasticloadbalancing:ModifyLoadBalancerAttributes",
                "elasticloadbalancing:ModifyRule",
                "elasticloadbalancing:ModifyTargetGroup",
                "elasticloadbalancing:ModifyTargetGroupAttributes",
                "elasticloadbalancing:RegisterTargets",
                "elasticloadbalancing:RemoveListenerCertificates",
                "elasticloadbalancing:RemoveTags",
                "elasticloadbalancing:SetIpAddressType",
                "elasticloadbalancing:SetSecurityGroups",
                "elasticloadbalancing:SetSubnets",
                "elasticloadbalancing:SetWebACL"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole",
                "iam:GetServerCertificate",
                "iam:ListServerCertificates"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cognito-idp:DescribeUserPoolClient"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "waf-regional:GetWebACLForResource",
                "waf-regional:GetWebACL",
                "waf-regional:AssociateWebACL",
                "waf-regional:DisassociateWebACL"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "tag:GetResources",
                "tag:TagResources"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "waf:GetWebACL"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "wafv2:GetWebACL",
                "wafv2:GetWebACLForResource",
                "wafv2:AssociateWebACL",
                "wafv2:DisassociateWebACL"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "shield:DescribeProtection",
                "shield:GetSubscriptionState",
                "shield:DeleteProtection",
                "shield:CreateProtection",
                "shield:DescribeSubscription",
                "shield:ListProtections"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}


kubectl get ingress
NAME           HOSTS                                    ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
auth-ingress   host.domain.com,sub-domain.host.domain.com             80      6s
```

As you can see, there is no address available.

Answer (score 1):

As per [this](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-alb-ingress-controller/issues/298) currently the ALB ingress controller cretaes new ALB for each ingress meaning there is no merge support.

Install the [merge ingress controller](https://github.com/jakubkulhan/ingress-merge) and remove the `annotationkubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb`

Also make sure to install the ALB ingress controller on the cluster.

https://akomljen.com/aws-alb-ingress-controller-for-kubernetes/

Comment: I don't have helm, any idea how I can use it without helm

Comment: don't think there is a way..but may be put values in the deployment yaml

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using the alb controller version 1.0.0. You can also use the upgrade version as there were memory leakage found to be see on this version.

Now going forward with the issue that you have been experiencing.
I understand that you wish to connect two or multiple service to the alb.

Steps:

1. Please check the logs :
   `kubectl logs -n kube-system $(kubectl get po -n kube-system | egrep -o 'alb-ingress[a-zA-Z0-9-]+') | grep '<ingress-name>'`
2. Remove this annotation kubernetes.io/ingress.class: merge for now.
3. Please check the public subnet has been tagged as kubernetes.io/role/elb to 1
4. If you have multiple services, add multiple backend services under the hosts

```
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /*
            backend:
              serviceName: ssl-redirect
              servicePort: use-annotation
          - path: /*
            backend:
              serviceName: service A
              servicePort: <port -A>
          - path: /<page>/*
            backend:
              serviceName: service B
              servicePort: <port-B>
```